# PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: How to resolve this?

Tags: python, directory, shutil, pathlib

I have asked this question and I couldn't figure out the solution. I've used different approach, shutil, pathlib but none of them work. Can someone help me resolve the issue I am having please? Thank you very much in advance for helping.

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Test.py",    
line 304, in <module>dir_path.rmdir()   # remove 
directory File "C:\Program Files\Python310
\lib\pathlib.py", line 1213, in rmdir 
self._accessor.rmdir(self) 

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access 
the file because it is being used by another process: 
'C:\\Test\\Folder2'
```

The Code:

```
from pathlib import Path

dir_path = Path.home() / 'C:/Test/Folder1/'
dir_path.rmdir()   # remove directory

dir_path = Path.home() / 'C:/Test/Folder2/'
dir_path.rmdir()   # remove directory
```

Comment: You are still having the folder or something in it open in some other process.

Comment: @KlausD. Test2 folder is empty when I attempt to delete it thru the script.